# Qt version mismatch error when compiling PySide2 app on Ubuntu (WSL), works fine on openSUSE

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyside2

I'm having a strange problem with a project I'm working on: it's written in Python 3 and uses PySide2, and PyInstaller for bundling.

When I compile it from openSUSE (WSL), the resulting binary can be run on that same openSUSE perfectly, and also on Ubuntu (WSL) without any problems.

But when I compile it from Ubuntu (WSL), it can't run anywhere and I get this error on Ubuntu:

```
relocation error: /.../app/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZN20QPlatformIntegration11screenAddedEP15QPlatformScreenb version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference
```

and this one on openSUSE:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Randomly, I will sometimes get this error on both:

```
libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.13' not found (required by /path/to/project)
```

I find it really weird that on Ubuntu, the compiled version doesn't even run on the same OS it was compiled on, whereas the openSUSE-compiled one works everywhere.